# how to maintain session between c++ client and java webservice

Tags: java, c++

We have a web application and web service in java [installed on tomcat 8], and a client program in c++ [installed on Apache http server].

The c++ code uses gSOAP to call the java webservice.

The application flow is:

1. browser access an URL on Apache HTTP server
2. c++ code redirects to Java application
3. Java application redirects back to c++ application [Java application adds some data in session]
4. c++ application calls Java webservice, in the webservice we try to get the session as:

```java
@Resource

private WebServiceContext wsContext;

MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();

HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession(false);

//.getSession(false)-this was done to get same session

//.getSession()-is returning new session, where our data is not present
```

How do we achieve this, I mean how to get the same session, from  where the webservice call is made?

Comment: Do you understand how are sessions maintained in general? Do you know how cookies or tokens work? If yes, then it should be straightforward to implement in a client written in any language.

Comment: Take a look at every set-cookie header sent in the response from the service. You will probably need these to "trick" the server into thinking the same entity is making all requests.